# VTL Template MACROS IN APIGW

Tags: aws-lambda

I do have a question regarding mapping templates in API Gateway. VTL allows us to set a variable, array or object but does it support usage of a macro? If yes, could you provide me with an example/guide?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, AWS has disabled #macro, #include, and #parse in both API Gateway and AppSync VTL.

You can use #define to achieve a similar result:

https://twitter.com/mappingtool/status/1488545743866630144